# Order places by newness?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I want to get a list of bars and order them by when they are added to Google Maps. [This](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.0327341,-73.7660467&radius=1000&type=bar&key=KEY) link will return the bars within 1,000 meters of a specific point. It is only in that area that I want to check. Looking at the [Places api](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) page, I do some see some options to order by but I am unable to see an option for newness.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option at this time. Like you've stated, the [Places API Nearby Search service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) does not currently have the option to sort place results by Google Maps date. You can either set a radius, or rank results by distance or prominence.

Hope this answers your question.